# Error when sync Product to Quickbooks Online using qbo api

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I have this issue when sync product to Quickbooks Online using qbo api.
The error is: "The account period has closed. Txn Date=01/16/2022 is before book closing date=03/31/2022"

This just happened a few hours ago (I think this issue related to this).

Can anyone explain to me this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you do a quick Google search, you'll find tons of information about what this is. The TLDR is that QuickBooks let's you set a date, before which nothing can be edited. You are trying to edit something prior to that date. Either don't edit that thing, or remove/change the closing date in QuickBooks before you make your edit.